# Promisifying API callbacks - How to properly resolve or reject

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, asp.net-web-api, es6-promise

I've read similar posts, but none quite hit on the head how to do this correctly.

I understand Promises and how they are typically created with success and failure listeners waiting to be triggered to either resolve or reject.

What I don't understand is when I'm **calling an API method that takes a success and failure callback as parameters**- how do I determine which callback is being triggered so I can then have it resolved or rejected?

For example with this Web API and considering the *navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition* method it offers:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

When the API sends back a success or error it will call one of the callbacks I gave it but **I don't know which one it's gonna call in order resolve or reject it.**

The question is then:
What is the proper way to listen for which callback is being triggered and how does it look to ES6 promisify the outcome of this kind of API call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

```
function getCurrentPositon(options){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){   
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
   });
}
```

You don't *know* which one is called, rather, you respond to both options - rejecting if it fails and fulfilling if it fulfilled.

Comment: Might want to add an example of how your promisified function is called and how the result and error come back through that which would complete the picture for the OP.